# Which work assignment is making medicine?

Tags: rimworld

I know you need medicine and crafting skills in the same pawn to make medicine, but which task is it in the work tab? I want to prioritize it for one of my workers.

I hope it's not Crafting, because I want them making medicine, not stuff like stone blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make medicine is indeed Crafting.

As per this [Steam Discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/294100/discussions/0/1693795812314073308/), with someone with a similar problem, the vanilla option is to create zones where your medicine man can't interact.

Comment: Note that you can also set a skill level. If your medicine man has skill 11 and you have a skill-3 pawn you want to only do blocks, set your medicine recipe to a minimum skill level of 10 to ensure that only the medicine man is able to start the job. The skill settings are great tools to have rookies only do menial jobs where the outcome quality is irrelevant (butchering, stonecutting, ...)